# Populate an array with Enum variable - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, enums

Okay, I have some code that populates an array from an enum variable in javascript.  However, it looks extremely outdated and clunky.

I'm wondering if any of you jquery / javascript gurus have a more elegant (best practice) method for this functionality.

CURRENT: (which works but is ugly)

```
var myEnum = {
first: 1,
second: 2,
third: 3};

if (Object.freeze)
Object.freeze(rolesEnum);
```

---

Creating Array (again works but very ugly)

```
var aEnumArray = [
            myEnum.first,
            myEnum.second,
            myEnum.third
            ];
        var aEnums = new Array();
        $.each(aEnumArray , function (i, x) {
            aEnums .push({
                id: x,
                name: Converters.rolesToStringConverter(x)
            });
        });

   aEnums.sort(function (x, y) { return (x.name == y.name) ? 0 : (x.name > y.name ? 1 : -1); });
```

---

Finally, after all of that, it is used to populate a

```
comboBox.clearItems();
comboBox.addItems(aEnums);
```

Sure is a lot of work just to populate a combo box.

Comment: That *is* a lot of work to populate a combo box. First, for sorting, you can use `x.name.localeCompare(y.name)` and skip the redundant ternary. Second, I'm not sure what the point of creating multiple arrays from the enum is. Third, if all this stuff is hidden in a module's functions, does it *really* matter?

Comment: LOL...you're right about does it really matter?  BUT - I'm just wanting best practices.  Thanks for the sort tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish, but from what I can tell I think this might help.

http://jsfiddle.net/HBVJu/

```
var myEnum = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
};
var enumsObj = [];
for(var prop in myEnum){
    enumsObj.push({id: myEnum[prop], name: prop})
}
```